# Why aren't my table headers showing despite being in HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I am currently working on a  project where I am using a table to display data. I have noticed that the table headers (`<th>` elements) are not showing up when the table is rendered in the browser. I have double-checked my HTML code and can confirm that the head elements are present and correctly structured, but for some reason, they are not being displayed in the table. I am looking for solutions on how to troubleshoot this issue and determine the cause of the problem. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <table id="exchange-rate">
    <tr>
      <th>AED</th>
      <th>NPR</th>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <div id="pagination-controls">
    <div id="numeric-pagination">
      <button class="page-button" id="page-1" onclick="renderPage(1)">1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    const API_URL = "https://api.fastforex.io/fetch-one?from=AED&to=NPR&api_key=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx";

    const PAGE_SIZE = 50;

    let exchangeRates = [];

    // Fetch exchange rate data from the API
    fetch(API_URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // Extract the exchange rate from the response data
        const rate = data.result.NPR;

        // Generate the exchange rate data for AED values from 1 to 100
        for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
          exchangeRates.push({
            aed: i,
            npr: (rate * i).toFixed(2)
          });
        }

        // Generate the exchange rate data for AED values from 100 to 900 in hundreds
        for (let i = 100; i <= 900; i += 100) {
          exchangeRates.push({
            aed: i,
            npr: (rate * i).toFixed(2)
          });
        }

        // Generate the exchange rate data for AED values from 1000 to 10000 in thousands
        for (let i = 1000; i <= 10000; i += 1000) {
          exchangeRates.push({
            aed: i,
            npr: (rate * i).toFixed(2)
          });
        }

        // Generate the numeric pagination buttons
        const NUM_PAGES = Math.ceil(exchangeRates.length / PAGE_SIZE);
        const numericPagination = document.getElementById("numeric-pagination");
        for (let i = 2; i <= NUM_PAGES; i++) {
          const button = document.createElement("button");
          button.classList.add("page-button");
          button.id = `page-${i}`;
          button.textContent = i;
          button.onclick = function() {
            renderPage(i);
          };
          numericPagination.appendChild(button);
        }

        // Render the first page
        renderPage(1);
      });

    // Get the table element
    const exchangeRateTable = document.getElementById("exchange-rate");

    function renderPage(page) {
      // Clear the table
      exchangeRateTable.innerHTML = "";

      // Calculate the starting and ending indices for the current page
      const startIndex = (page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE;
      const endIndex = startIndex + PAGE_SIZE;

      // Get the exchange rates for the current page
      const pageRates = exchangeRates.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

      // Populate the table with the exchange rates for the current page
      for (const {
          aed,
          npr
        } of pageRates) {
        // Create a new table row
        const row = document.createElement("tr");

        // Create the AED and NPR cell elements
        const aedCell = document.createElement("td");
        const nprCell = document.createElement("td");

        // Set the text content of the cells to the AED and NPR values
        aedCell.textContent = `${aed} AED`;
        nprCell.textContent = `${npr} NPR`;

        // Append the cells to the row
        row.appendChild(aedCell);
        row.appendChild(nprCell);

        // Append the row to the table
        exchangeRateTable.appendChild(row);
      }

      // Highlight the current page button
      document.querySelector('.page-button.active').classList.remove('active');
      document.getElementById(`page-${page}`).classList.add('active');
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: I can't see any `thead` element in the table ..? Even if they are there, `exchangeRateTable.innerHTML = ""` clears everything in the table, including the thead elements. That said, you're talking about "_the HTML head elements_", if those mean [`<head>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head#technical_summary), they're not a part of the table and should not contain any visible content at all. If you'll add some, it's automatically moved to `body` by the parser.

Comment: no i was taking about 'th' element

Comment: you need to add it by yourself just like td it will not generate automatically

Comment: Well, you're removing `th`s when clearing the table. Include `tbody` element in your table, and give the id to `tbody` instead of `table`, then your code should work.

Comment: `<table><thead><tr><th>AED</th><th>NPR</th></tr></thead><tbody id="exchange-rate"></tbody></table>`

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues that are due to invalid HTML and there are several issues that can be vastly improved.

Uncomment the fetch to get back to what you had.

1. Use thead and tbody and add the ID to the tbody
2. create the arrays using map and template literals and have one DOM update

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // Get the table element
  const exchangeRateTable = document.getElementById("exchange-rate");
  const pagination = document.getElementById("numeric-pagination");
  const PAGE_SIZE = 5;
  // Fetch exchange rate data from the API
  //    fetch(API_URL)
  //      .then(response => response.json())
  //      .then(data => {
  // Extract the exchange rate from the response data
  //        const rate = data.result.NPR;
  const rate = 35.47997;

  const exchangeRates = Array.from({
      length: 10000
    })
    .map((_, i) => ({
      aed: (i+1),
      npr: (rate * (i+1)).toFixed(2)
    }));

  // Generate the numeric pagination buttons
  const NUM_PAGES = Math.ceil(exchangeRates.length / PAGE_SIZE);
  pagination.innerHTML = Array.from({
      length: NUM_PAGES
    })
    .map((_, i) => `<button class="page-button${i===0 ? ' active' : ''}" id="page-${i+1}">${i+1}</button> `)
    .join('');
  //}); // end of fetch
  const renderPage = (page) => {
    // Calculate the starting and ending indices for the current page
    const startIndex = (page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE;
    const endIndex = startIndex + PAGE_SIZE;

    // Get the exchange rates for the current page
    const pageRates = exchangeRates.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    exchangeRateTable.innerHTML = pageRates
      .map(({
        aed,
        npr
      }) => `<tr><td>${aed} AED</td><td>${npr} NPR</td></tr>`)
      .join('');
    // Highlight the current page button
    document.querySelector('.page-button.active').classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById(`page-${page}`).classList.add('active');

  };
  pagination.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    renderPage(tgt.textContent);
  });
  renderPage(1);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green
}

#numeric-pagination {
  width: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>AED</th>
      <th>NPR</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="exchange-rate"></tbody>
</table>
<div id="pagination-controls">
  <div id="numeric-pagination"></div>
</div>
```